# .Cer or Pfx file which one need to used for WCF secure communication

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, certificate

We know that....
`cer` - certificate stored in the X.509 standard format. This certificate contains information about the certificate's owner... along with public and private keys.

`pfx` - stands for personal exchange format. It is used to exchange public and private objects in a single file. A pfx file can be created from .cer file. Can also be used to create a Software Publisher Certificate.

when we try to secure WCF communication then what kind of certificate we should use....Cer or Pfx file ?

please guide. thanks

Comment: Windows favors PFX/PKCS #12. PFX/PKCS #12 are not exactly the same, but they are mostly similar. You can use OpenSSL's [`pkcs12`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html) utility to build the PFX file. The trick is to ensure you start with a single server certificate that *includes* all intermediate certificates in the same file (but not the CA certificate). Lots of related questions on Stack Overflow: [Windows IIS PFX](http://www.google.com/#q=windows+pfx+iis+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: cert or pfx which file is used maximum time in wcf security ?